# select rows on condition + one row on different condition

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I'm sorry for the bad title. But I dont know how to explain it shortly.

Consider a datatable with 'ID' column with an clustered index on ID Descending. Its containing another column, where Null-Values only exist in the upper most entries. Lets call this column 'NewValue' and it does not have an index.

Now I'm pulling a specific resultset and I can do so in two different ways:

First way:

```
Select Top (Select Count([NewValue]) + 1 from [testtable] where [NewValue] is Null) * from [testable]
```

Second way:

```
Select * from [testable] where [NewValue] is Null Union Select Top 1 * from [testtable] where [NewValue] is not Null
```

I do not understand enough from execution plans to know myself which is better, but I see there is quiet a difference. The second way does a sort that takes 53%, which doesnt happen in the first method. I'm using MSSQL-Server

So can you tell me which is better? I need all datarows with 'NewValue' = Null and the first datarow where it is not null

Comment: It's probably be easier for someone to assist if you post A) the table structure, including indexes and B) the query plan, use a tool like https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. Note that the first option does not guarantee that only the `NULL` rows plus one more will be included, it's aribitrary

Comment: In this case it is guaranteed, because there will be no null value after a non null value. In the order of the datarows.

Comment: Rows in SQL tables are *unordered*. If you don't specify `ORDER BY` the server is free to return rows to you in whatever order it chooses as most efficient. The order can and does change.

Comment: No in my tests it returns them always in the order that the clustered index is applying to it